# Trouble plotting a function constructed using NIntegrate and FindRoot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, function-construction

Here is my code:

```
f0[y_] := 1/(E^((1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
f1[y_] := 1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
l[y_] := f1[y]/f0[y]
opts = {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}, AccuracyGoal -> 8}
h0[ϵ0_?NumericQ, ϵ1_?NumericQ] := 
  -(ϵ1/(1 - ϵ0)) + 
  NIntegrate[f0[y]*Boole[l[y] < (1 - ϵ0)/(1 - ϵ1)], {y, -∞, ∞}, 
    {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None},AccuracyGoal -> 8}] - 
  ((1 - ϵ1) * 
    NIntegrate[f1[y]*Boole[l[y] < (1 - ϵ0)/(1 - ϵ1)], {y, -∞,∞}, 
    {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}, AccuracyGoal -> 8}])/(1 - ϵ0)
hh0[ϵ0_] := 
  FindRoot[h0[ϵ0, ϵ1] == 0, {ϵ1, 0.5}, 
    StepMonitor :>Print["Step to ϵ0 = ", ϵ0, Evaluate@opts]]
Plot[hh0[ϵ0], {ϵ0, 0, 1}]
```

I am able to get all the values that are necessery to plot, but the plot doesnt output any graphics. How can I fix this problem?Improved formatting

Comment: If you try `hh0[x]` for some values of `x`, you will see there is a convergence problem with your integrals.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut hh0[0.1] gives me for example 0.77327. hh0[0.5] gives me 0.315573 ... I can get single numbers. Integrals are definitely correct if I havent mistype anything but i tried again.

Comment: Interesting, I get the same values, but with lots of messages of this kind:
`NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small`

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it is not only you who gets that message. I get many of them. But eventually there is a result))

Comment: Ok, solved. Type `Plot[ϵ1 /. hh0[ϵ0], {ϵ0, 0, 1}]`. Since you are calling FindRoot, you don't get a value but a list. With `/.` you can retrieve the value.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut great I was just about to think that, It is not giving a value, right.. thank you very much.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut answer the question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer from my previous comment, as suggested by Öskå.

Since you are calling `FindRoot`, you don't get a value but a list. With `/.` you can retrieve the value:

```
Plot[ϵ1 /. hh0[ϵ0], {ϵ0, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I added a picture, I hope you don't mind :)